# How to insert a movie in latex without a title using \multimedia in from the beamer package?

Tags: latex, beamer

The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) of the beamer package states on page 133:

```
 \usepackage{multimedia} %in the preamble
 \movie[⟨options⟩]{⟨poster text⟩}{⟨movie filename⟩}
```

"This command will insert the movie with the filename ⟨movie filename⟩ into the pdf file." I tried different option e.g.

```
 \movie[label=false,width=1.0\textwidth,poster,autostart,showcontrols]
```

but wasn't able to find out how to insert a movie without the movie-title displayed above it?

Comment: Solved, the title of the movie displayed above the video seem to appear due to the fact I've been embedding a .webm video, it disappears when using mp4 or avi.